# How to call multiple onclick events from one button/a href link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, smarty

I have the following code:

```
<input id="unassignButton" class="unassignButton" type="button" value="[[Unassign]]" onclick="javscript:unassignImage({$file.sid},{$listing_sid});"/>
```

In the end code, multiple inputs like that might be generated `{$file.sid},{$listing_sid}`

So I can have, for example:

```
<input class="unassignButton" type="button" value="Unassign" onclick="javscript:unassignImage(1533,185);">
<input class="unassignButton" type="button" value="Unassign" onclick="javscript:unassignImage(1558,290);">
```

Now I want to create a link that will call the "onclick" function `javscript:unassignImage` of all the inputs that have the unassignButton ID one by one, with the proper parameters being considered `unassignImage(1558,290)...`

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance,
Arky

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#unassignAll").on('click', function () {
    $(".unassignButton").trigger('click');
});
```

This will call the `click` callback bound to all of the unassign buttons simultaneously.

Comment: +1 for a clever solution.  Would love to see Arky do something that wasn't so obtrusive in the first place

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick answer! In my defense, I'm modifying a "Classifieds Script" kind of software, and my programming skills are laughable at best so... :)

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off assigning the click handler within javascript instead of the markup. also - make sure you don't give each button the same id `unassignButton` because ids should always be unique, whereas classes can be shared:

The markup with data attributes:

```
<input id="{someUniqueId}" class="unassignButton" type="button" value="[[Unassign]]" data-fileSid="{$file.sid}" data-listingSid="{$listing_sid}"/>
```

The javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // bind click handler to each button using the data attributes above
    $('input.unassignButton').on('click', function(){
        unassignImage($(this).data('fileSid'),$(this).data('listingSid'));
    });

    // bind click handler to 'unassignAll' button/link (assumes you have a button with class 'unassignAll'
    $('input.unassignAll').on('click', function(){
        $('input.unassignButton').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

See [the Jquery docs on .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for more info about data attributes